# i'm practicing the if statement but i keep getting the error "can not find symbol"

Tags: java

```
package practicejava;

class TestConstructor {

    public String myName;

    public int myAge = 19;

    if (myAge = 18){

      myName = "joe";

    }

}
```

// my question is how would i be able to use myAge in the if statement properly?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` to check for equality.

Comment: Your code should be inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your code in fuction
2. Change `=` to `==` in if()

> if (myAge == 18)

`=` is assignment operator

Answer (score 0):

It's much worse than that: This is not Java.

You can't put code in the middle of a class like that.  It belongs in a method or constructor.

Try it like this:

```
class TestConstructor {

    public String myName;

    public int myAge = 19;

    public TestConstructor(String name, int age) {
        myName = name;
        myAge = age;
        if (myAge == 18) {
            myName = "joe";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember when you were the only person nice to me in my times of struggle lmao. Thanks brother

Comment: Sorry, is this sarcasm?  Why now after 16 months?

Comment: i was just going through my old questions laughing at how ridiculous they were lol.